# Restoring data from corrupt btrfs RAID 1

Tags: btrfs, corruption

I had a BTRFS RAID 1 array that I was storing my data. I had accidently reformatted as an RAID 1 using MDADM, before I noticed my error unmounted everything.

Now my tree seems to be corrupted, I'm having trouble restoring any data at all.

I had used btrfs restore chunk repair, and ran for 1 day. Now I'm trying to mount it but having trouble.

```
$ sudo btrfs filesystem show /dev/sdd
warning, device 2 is missing
Label: none  uuid: 7715ded7-e464-41a8-8b2b-ca8ec9af95ee
        Total devices 2 FS bytes used 896.00KiB
        devid    1 size 3.64TiB used 2.03GiB path /dev/sdd
        *** Some devices missing

$ sudo mount -o degraded -t btrfs /dev/sdd /mnt/d
mount: /mnt/d: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

`btrfs check init-extent-tree` doesn't seem to work either.

Any other suggestions?